# Spring SessionAttributes or httpsession

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-session

In my Spring MVC project I have a jsp page , registration page , in which there is a form. In this form the user inserts his data (name, surname and so on).I created a bean User and I bound the form with this bean.But now I have a problem.How can i put the user object into a session in a method of a controller?
Can I use `@SessionAttributes`,httpsession or I set the scope of the bean to session? How can i solve it?Sorry for my English. Thanks

Comment: So u need to set user object in session?

Comment: I don't know if it's better to set user object in HttpSession, or to set the object in @SessionAttributes or to set the bean as scope=session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpSession` so just need to set your user object in your session and access anywhere into the system.

[Refer this httpsession documentation for setting session value.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: What's the differences between httpsession and @SessionAttributes?

Comment: @SessionAttribute does not have to use the http session. It uses a SessionAttributeStore which can have anything as its backing storage. Only the default implementation uses the httpsession.

Comment: So, if I want to put something into the session it's better that I use an http session? What's the differences between http session and SessionAttributeStore?So, if I want to put something into the session it's etter than I put it into an http session?

Comment: Yes use httpsession is better approach.

Comment: Sorry, but if i create a bean with scope session , Spring put it into http session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65820/discussion-between-harshal-patil-and-alex).